# Preventing checkbox labels from moving underneath checkboxes on viewport shrink in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've made a large form filled with checkboxes using the Bootstrap grid system.  Each checkbox has its own `.col-xs-*` class, to keep things aligned and looking clean.

The problem is that when a user shrinks the viewport, some labels will move underneath the checkboxes, which looks a little messy:

[image]

To fix this problem, I've just been making the `col-*` classes larger (e.g. changing `.col-xs-4` to `.col-xs-5`) or adding `.form-group` and `.form-control` classes to create "checkboxey areas", but I imagine that there might be a cleaner solution.

- Is there a Bootstrappy way to keep these checkboxes aligned (when the width of the label exceeds the `col-xs-*` container's width)?
- Are there some simple CSS rules I can use to apply fixes to these form fields?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oLzyLvc4/) example of how my form looks right now.

Answer (score 1):

Put this:

```
.space {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

in your css file and apply it to your divs. It will remove the spaces and make your form fields look good.

Comment: Solid answer, but if I use this, then all of the checkbox labels overlap. http://jsfiddle.net/kjn80oe0/